# My Laptop has outgoing UDP packets on high numbered ports several times a second

Tags: virus, trojan, bot

I originally noticed this on my router firewall, so I installed Zone Alarm in order to look more closely, and now I can see it in the ZA logs. I have run virus scans from Kaspersky, Trend Micro, & Windows Defender, and the scans all come up clean. I have looked in my program files, my add-ons, and didn't see anything strange. I disabled unnecessary services and tasks, with no change. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this off my computer?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is a link to a pic of my firewall log.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6sxs.jpg
Cheers, K

Comment: [You probably shouldn't be using multiple antivirus programs](https://blog.kaspersky.com/multiple-antivirus-programs-bad-idea/2670/).

Answer (score 7):

Those UDP packets all seem to go to a [public DNS server](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/security-services/public-dns/index.xhtml). Considering the destination port is 53, it is highly likely you are doing DNS queries and not something malicious.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. So it is normal for several of these to happen every second, even when I'm not using my computer?

Comment: @KeraKatera Modern OSes, both Windows and Mac, have services running in the background that perform a variety of tasks, like searching for updates. If you ran an anti-virus scan and it came up clean, it is unlikely that you have a virus.

Answer (score 2):

I backed up my files, re-formatted my hard drive and re-installed Windows 10 and the problem disappeared. I no longer have hundreds of dns requests every minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal, that it happens every second, and malicious traffic can be hidden inside DNS queries.

But because the target is known public DNS server (as mentioned above) it is more likely to be a misconfiguration or some other error than malicious traffic. This is more likely, because it disappeared after you re-installed your os.